# Button not changing its image state to "pressed"

Tags: android, imagebutton, selected

I am trying to do a simple selector.

Here is my selector xml code, its called "butt.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_off" android:state_pressed="false"/> <!-- default -->
```

thats the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:src="@drawable/butt" />
```

and thats the code:

```
ImageButton ib;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ib.setSelected(true);

}
```

My problem is that the state is not changing, when i press and hold on the button. It is changing its image to the `"selected"` one when I pressed. But when I release my finger, it is getting back to the `"not sellected"` state.

Why is that so?  How can I make it stay in "Selected" mode?

Comment: set your butt.xml as background.
android:background ="@drawable/butt"

Comment: sorry, not working even after i did android:background ="@drawable/butt" instead of android:src="@drawable/butt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use selector if you need to show a button's state as selected or non-selected.

Instead you have to setBackground() using code and by managing a flag you can check that your button is currently selected or not.

Like

```
if(flag)
    btn.setDrawableBackground(R.id.btn_activate_on)
else
    btn.setDrawableBackground(R.id.btn_activate_off)
```

If you want to show the effect on state press create Two selectors with opposite states.

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_on"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_off"></item>
```

and another one is

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_off"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_on"></item>
```

Comment: this will work but its not exactly what i want...  because that the image will change only when i release me finger and not when I touch it...

Comment: You can do 1 thing then. Create Two selectors with opposite states. See i have updated that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your selector butt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_activate_off"/>

</selector>
```

Also yuo can remove this line `ib.setSelected(true);` from your `onClick()`. It will be taken care off.
**UPDATE**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt" />
```

You need to set the background instead of setting the src.

Comment: I did the changes you said and its still doing the same thing.

Comment: You sure your images are different? btn_activate_on and btn_activate_off are different? Also remove the line ib.setSelected(true); I ahve used the exact same code and it works for me. Try cleaning the project!

Comment: Yes, I am sure. what you are doing is only changing the image at the time of the press, but when you lift your finger up it gets back to the first image. i want it to stay pressed.

Answer (score 1):

A button shouldn't be used for toggling like that - use a checkbox instead.

"Selected" for a button means that the user currently has their finger down on the button, so when the user lifts their finger it won't be selected anymore.